# How does "Gboard Voice Typing" work without asking RECORD_AUDIO permission?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, gboard

So I built my own custom keyboard, currently adding Speech-to-Text functionality.

Using SpeechRecognizer class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer

I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` permission in manifest, which is used by older devices.
Newer devices need to ask such a permission on the fly, before using it.

If I request "RECORD_AUDIO" permission, everything works.

If I don't request it, I get error code "9", which means "SpeechRecognition won't work because permission was not supplied".

Makes sense.

However, I installed Googles Gboard virtual keyboard, and there clicking on record button, it just starts, without asking for permission. WHY?

I also checked in gboards settings, I haven't given it permission to use microphone, yet it just... does use it.

Comment: I can confirm this on Pixel 2 / Android v10. I hope it's a bug in Gboard... Have you asked Google for an explanation?

Comment: No, I haven't. Confirmed on Samsung Galaxy S5mini and Huawei P20 Pro.